# Problem with getting the event embed code to post it into website

Tags: facebook-events, facebook-developers

I am working on embedding a Facebook post into a website of mine and I just ran into a snag. I have an event: https://www.facebook.com/events/1201868446535694/ and obviously it is a public and available event, but when I tried to get the embeddable code from Facebook developers screen, it throws the following error message: 
`This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.`

[image]

I don't understand why I would be getting this error message, when obviously the post exists and it is set to public. Am I doing something wrong?

It hasn't even gotten to the point where I can embed the code. I'm still at the Facebook developer's screen and Facebook is telling me the event doesn't exist. So I guess the question more is: why would Facebook be telling me the post doesn't exist, when it obviously does, and what can I do to fix that problem?

Comment: The link no longer work. This question might need to be updated to replace the event link with instructions about how to get a an equivalent URL.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this myself, using your event.

I also got the error message - but when I scrolled down there was also a Get Code button (as you did) - and I was able to use it to get code.

Perhaps you should try getting the code and installing it.

The other thought I would have is that you are using the Embed Post option to try to embed an Event.   But a Post is not the same as an Event.  It may be that Embed Post does not work with events, and that the Social Plugins kit doesn't actually include an option for embedding events.

Comment: 1. I tried just embedding it into my code, just for kicks, and it came through with the error message

Comment: 2. That's a good point. I hadn't thought about that, that's probably true that an event wouldn't be considered the same as a post.